# Total Revenue in GA4 for non ecommerce sites

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Im using GA4 for my website which is not an Ecommerce, it's just a blog. Ive created some events and Im sending a "value" where Im adding "amounts of money" for click. Events have been conerted to conversion in the "Conversions" option in GA4 however when I check the events report under the "Total Revenue" metric, I only see $0 however based on the amount of events "Total Revenue" should be more than $0.

Below the screenshot of my Tag Manager Tag for the event:
[Tag Manager Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7X4U.png)

And here is the picture of my GA4 48 hours after the event was fired and coverted to conversion:
[GA4 Events Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIqOO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send the `purchase` event to affect Total Revenue. Custom events don't affect Total Revenue. There's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events#custom_events) that "Custom events won't show up in most standard reports so you will likely need to set up custom reporting for meaningful analysis.". If you keep the custom event "click_suscripcion", you'll need to use the "Event Value" metric to see the total of the value parameter.

Comment: If I modify the original purchase event(for example changing the event name based on other sent parameters) it will be recognized as conversion but will not populate the total revenue column, why?